# Using coroutine channels and the livedata builder together

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

How might I use coroutine channels together with the livedata coroutine builder `(androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx architecture component)` to continuously listen for messages produced from a websocket library to a `ReceiveChannel<String>`?

My first thought is to implement it like this

```
val user: LiveData<String> = liveData {
    while(true) {
        val data = myWebsocketChannel.receive() //Channel suspend function
        emit(data)
    }
}
```

But this feels a bit "non-kotliny" and my gut is telling me that there is a better of solving this.
Is there a better way of handling posting data once received from a coroutine channel?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    myWebsocketChannel.consumeEach { data ->
       emit(data)
   }
}
```

`myWebsocketChannel.consumeEach { ... }` is going to iterate forever (suspending, if channel is empty) until someone closes the `myWebsocketChannel`. On the producer side - where we are listening to the socket, we should be careful to not close channel prematurely.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Would this stop running once there are no more items queued in the channel?

Comment: It will stop running if someone invokes channel.close() at the "other side" of the channel.  Otherwise it will iterate indefinitely (suspending if channel is empty).